# uniform cost search algorithm with python

Tags: python, algorithm, search

Consider a state space where the start state is 2 and each state `k` has three successors: numbers `2k, 2k+1, 2k+2`. The cost from state k to each respective child is `k, ground(k/2), k+2`.

I would like to implement a uniform-cost-search algorithm with python. The goal state is number 85.

Comment: Just to understand to get from 2 to 85 one possibility are the following state transitions: 2 [2k+1] -> 5 [2k] -> 10 [2k+1] -> 21 [2k] -> 42 [2k+1] ->85 with cost 1+5+5+21+21=51. Do I understand the problem correct?

Comment: @SaiBot right, it is correct. But I need the python code because calculating manually takes huge time ! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an array, initially 0s representing each state (0..85).

Iterate from start state (2) to goal /2 (85/2)

At each state compute the possible successor, and the cost if you were to move there from the current state (the cost of the current state is in the array).

Update the costs at the possitions compute if the cost you just computed is lower than whatever was there before, or it was 0 before.

Take the cost from the array corresponding to the goal state. If it's 0 it's impossible to reach.

Code should look something like this

```
import math
goal = 85
state = [-1] * (goal + 1)
state[2] = 0
for k in range(2 , goal/2 + 1):
  if state[k] < 0: continue
  for pos, cost in [
        (k*2, k),
        (k*2 + 1, math.floor(k/2)),
        (k*2+2, k+2)]:
    if pos > goal: continue
    if state[pos] == -1 or state[pos] > state[k] + cost:
      state[pos] = state[k] + cost
      # Possibly store k somewhere to build the solution.
print state[goal]
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Can you provide the python code? I faced some problems in implementing it. nodes should not be list because they are associated path cost and node cost. this makes it a bit complicated for me. thx again.

Comment: @Cina Added, but you should post your code next time.